# python: module name with prefix '.'

Tags: python

Is it possible to have a module named `.mymodule.py`? If so, how should I import it?

Trying to hide a module from regular `ls` and `rm`.

Comment: Not trivially, since a period has meaning in import statements

Comment: `"Trying to hide a module from regular ls and rm"` that sounds... questionable. Why? especially that `ls -a` will "find" it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to name a python module with prefix `.`

> Take a look at python module naming convention: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names